# My App works on Gingerbread... Crash on ICS and HC

Tags: java, android, android-layout, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I need your help.
My App works fine on GingerBread, but on ICS and HC crash.
This is the logcat

```
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.bozz.milaircraft.f23$ImageAdapter.getView(f23.java:125)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-14 20:26:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nomeF22Raptor"
            android:textColor="#FFD800"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbutton" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/datiF22Raptor" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/cartecF22Raptor" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/utilizzatoriF22Raptor" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <Gallery
                        android:id="@+id/gallery"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" >
                    </ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the java code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class f23 extends Activity {



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.f23);

        Button bhome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homebutton);
        bhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.bozz.milaircraft.MENU"));
            }
        });

        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("BRIEFING");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("DESIGN");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("USERS");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag4");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        specs.setIndicator("GALLERY");
        th.addTab(specs);


        Gallery ga = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));



    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        /** The parent context */
        private Context myContext;
        int imageBackground;

        /** URL-Strings to some remote images. */
        private String[] myRemoteImages = {
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_1.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_2.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_3.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_4.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_5.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_6.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_7.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_8.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_9.jpg",
                "http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_10.jpg"};

        /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            this.myContext = c;

        }

        /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
        public int getCount() {
            return this.myRemoteImages.length;
        }

        /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new ImageView to be displayed, depending on the position
         * passed.
         */
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);

            try {
                /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();
                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                i.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.f4_1);
                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
            }

            /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(480, 640));
            return i;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views depending on the
         * 'offset' to the center.
         */
        public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
            return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float) Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
        }
    }
}
```

The App crash when I click on the Gallery Tab.

Answer (score 8):

It is a bad idea to perform (potentially blocking) network operations on your app's main thread, which is what you are doing. Before Honeycomb (Android 3.0), it was just a bad idea. From Android 3.0 onwards, it is prohibited, and you receive this exception if you try to do so.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

You need to farm out this network logic to a separate asynchronous thread. Or, look at a `Handler`. You're going to need to change your code architecture; no easy fix.

Comment: It's prohibited, but If user1149727 wants to continue cranking out apps that exhibit unacceptable blocking behaviour it's possible to disable [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Answer (score 4):

In Honeycomb networking is [not allowed on the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). The reason is that it slows down the user interface (UI).

Instead try to download your images in an background thread, the easiest way to implement this is using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use it at your own risk:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.permitAll()
.build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Resource: 
**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html**

Answer (score 1):

You can see the version of the OS, and execute a code depending of it.

For example:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solve the problem:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class f24 extends Activity {

    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> PhotoURLS = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.f24);

        Button bhome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homebutton);
        bhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.bozz.milaircraft.MENU"));
            }
        });


        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("BRIEFING");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("DESIGN");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("USERS");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag4");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        specs.setIndicator("GALLERY");
        th.addTab(specs);

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.GalleryView);
        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
        g.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                imgView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(PhotoURLS
                        .get(position)));
                imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            }
        });

        // replace this code to set your image urls in list
        PhotoURLS.add("http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_1.jpg");
        PhotoURLS.add("http://www.medicinarozzano.it/images/milair/f4_1.jpg");

        new AddImageTask().execute();

    }

    class AddImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            for (String url : PhotoURLS) {
                String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        url.length());
                filename = "th_" + filename;
                String thumburl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                imageAdapter.addItem(LoadThumbnailFromURL(thumburl + filename));
                publishProgress();
                //SystemClock.sleep(200);
            }

            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        }
    }

    private Drawable LoadThumbnailFromURL(String url) {
        try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            boolean isImage = contentType.startsWith("image/");
            if(isImage){
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httpRequest);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

                InputStream is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src Name");
                return d;
            } else {
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
                return d;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url) {
        try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            boolean isImage = contentType.startsWith("image/");
            if(isImage){
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httpRequest);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(
                        entity);
                InputStream is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();

                // Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o);

                // The new size we want to scale to
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 150;

                // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                int scale = 1;
                while (true) {
                    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                            || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp /= 2;
                    height_tmp /= 2;
                    scale *= 2;
                }

                // Decode with inSampleSize
                is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
                return d;
            } else {
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
                return d;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        ArrayList<Drawable> drawablesFromUrl = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        public void addItem(Drawable item) {
            drawablesFromUrl.add(item);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return drawablesFromUrl.size();
        }

        public Drawable getItem(int position) {
            return drawablesFromUrl.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageDrawable(drawablesFromUrl.get(position));
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

            return i;
        }
    }

}
```

But now I have another problem:

If i don not declare any SDK on Android Manifest, the app works perfectly on both gingerbread and HC, and ICS. However, if i declare a minimum SDK greater than 1 or TargetSDK, the app works fine on gingerbread but not on HC and ISC. When i click on an image in the gallery nothing appears on the image viewer. Yet, a toast error pops up.

Also, if there is no internet connection the app crashes.

Best regards
Tiberio Bozotti

EDIT:
i could remove the SDK but on honeycomb it is not clear. Meaning that the layout is not compatible.

Comment: this is not a forum - If you found that an answer helped you, please marked it as solved by clicking the green tickbox. If you have further questions, please post them as a new question and try to reduce the amount of code posted to a small isolated problem. Learn more in the http://stackoverflow.com/faq